# Undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass - when I click on Form Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have added validation to the form [FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Zwp.png). So whenever I click on the create employee with all the details it works but when I do not put the values I get this error. I have even changed to @employee in form_with.

I just want validations to be seen. How do I handle this?

Employees Controller:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: %i[ show edit update destroy]

  # GET /employees or /employees.json
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  # GET /employees/1 or /employees/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  # GET /employees/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /employees or /employees.json
  def create
    employee_service = EmployeeCreationService.new(employee_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if employee_service.execute!
        format.html { redirect_to employee_service.employee}
        # format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        # format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1 or /employees/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @employee}
        # format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        # format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employees/1 or /employees/1.json
  def destroy
    @employee.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url}
      # format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :phone, :designation_id, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_with(model: employee, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if employee.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(employee.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employee from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% employee.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :name,class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :phone,class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= form.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
  </div> 

 
 <div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :designation_id,class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= form.select :designation_id, [["SOFTWARE ENGINEER", "2"], ["SERVICE ENGINEER", "3"]] %>
    
    </div>
  </div> 


  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :Email,class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= email_field_tag 'employee[email]' %>
    </div>
  </div> 

   <div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :Password,class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= password_field_tag 'employee[password]' %>
    </div>
  </div> 

<br />

  <div class='form-group'>
    <div class="align-left">
      <h5 align="left">
      <%= form.submit class:"btn btn-dark"%>
      </h5></button>

    </div>
  <div class="align">
    <div >&nbsp;
    <%= link_to 'Go Back', employees_path , class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

<% end %>
```

Service - to create employee and User simultaneously(Using Devise):

```
class EmployeeCreationService
    attr_reader :employee
    def initialize(employee_params)
        @employee_params = employee_params.except(:email, :password)
        @user_params = employee_params.slice(:email, :password)
    end

    def execute!
        begin
            @employee = Employee.create!(@employee_params)
            User.create!(@user_params.merge(employee: employee))
        rescue => exception
            @ex =  exception
            return false  
        end
        true
    end
end
```

Comment: you are doing `employee.errors.any?`, try with `@employee.errors.any?`

Comment: @arieljuod No, it did not solve

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem in the `create` action in `else` branch of condition:
The form needs that `@employee` variable should be set but it isn't for this case.
You need to have the ability to have an instance of the Employee class from your service. Something like this:

```rb
@employee = employee_service.execute!
if @employee.valid?
  redirect_to
else
  render
```

Comment: undefined method `valid?' for false:FalseClass,
I'm getting this.

I'm a newbie to rails

Comment: @Sameer_99 you need to change the implementation of the service class - it should return not True/False but Employee instance.

Comment: Thank you , I was able to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_valid)
    employee_service = EmployeeCreationService.new(employee_params)
    

    respond_to do |format|
      if employee_service.execute!
        format.html { redirect_to employee_service.employee}
        
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        
      end
    end
  end
```

Made these changes and it works fine now. For the validations, I have added JS.

Also slice employeee params with only the name phone and designation.